# Move ext/hash from resources to objects php PHP 7.2 migration

Tags: php, migration, compatibility, php-7.2

> As part of the long-term migration away from resources, the Hash
>   extension has been updated to use objects instead of resources. The
>   change should be seamless for PHP developers, except for where
>   is_resource() checks have been made (which will need updating to
>   is_object() instead).

The "[Hash extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) has been update to use objects instead of resources
I do not understand

1) Where in the "hash extension" is there this change represented?.

2) the second sentences "which will need update", refers, I understand to is_resource in a Hash function (extension part), but, how this is the case exactly? 
Which will be an exact example that "should be replaced" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 7.2 a method like...

```
<?php
$ctx = hash_init('md5');
var_dump($ctx);
```

...would output something like `resource(7, Hash Context)`. The returned value was a "resource".

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource.

As of 7.2 they changed that to return an actual object (class) of type [HashContext](http://php.net/manual/en/class.hashcontext.php).

You would therefor possibly need to change how the return value of those hash functions are being evaluated.

Where before you might simply check `is_resource()` (possibly `get_resource_type()`) now you would use [`is_a`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) or `instanceof`.

```
if ($h instanceof \HashContext) { ...
```

Really depends on the code. You might not need to change anything. Depends if/how/where your code evaluates the return values of some of those functions. Stuff you might find in a unit test...

For example, this code would still work pre/post 7.2 even though `$ctx` changes type:

```
$ctx = hash_init('md5');
hash_update($ctx, 'The quick brown fox ');
hash_update($ctx, 'jumped over the lazy dog.');
echo hash_final($ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Are you a PHP core active contributor?, I see you have answered a lot of my questions related to this kind of "small details" (Y)

Comment: Sadly no. Just a long time coder in the language. Wish I had the time and ability to contribute more. Glad to have helped you though!